# filtrar por parámetro especifico dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Buen dia,estoy trabajando con javascript y estoy tratando de filtrar los elementos que terminen en .jpg que estan dentro de un array

```
var archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg","tarea.pdf","video.mp4","fondo.jpg"];
```

lo que necesito es que me imprima solo los elementos que terminen en .jpg, no se si es posible o debo de cambiar la estructura del array

he intentado algo como esto.

```js
var archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg","tarea.pdf","video.mp4","fondo.jpg"];
    for (var i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
   if (archivos[i]=== ".jpg") {
    console.log(archivos[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Nos compartirías por favor lo que hayas intentado?

Comment: Comparte aquello que hayas intentado jose fuentes, así nosotros podremos ayudarte así como dice Beta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prueba esto

```js
var archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg","tarea.pdf","video.mp4","fondo.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
  img = archivos[i]
  if (img.endsWith(".jpg")) {
    console.log(img)
    // tu_funcion_para_imprimir()
  }
}
```

[Método `endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/endsWith)

Comment: muchas gracias si funciona!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar el método [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para crear un nuevo `array` con la condición que necesites, en este caso utilizaremos [Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) para determinar si el archivo tiene la *extensión deseada*.

```js
const archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg","tarea.pdf","video.mp4","fondo.jpg"];

const fotos = archivos.filter((f) => f.includes(".jpg"));

console.log(fotos);
```

Comment: Iba a usar filter tambien pero se me olvido completamente que existia el metodo endsWith... vaya. igual no me parece mala respuesta, lo unico es que podría fallar si la extensión no se encuentra al final (si se encuentra en un punto intermedio igualmente la meteria en las fotos, cosa que no es lo ideal si por ejemplo al final no hay extensión...)

Answer (score 4):

Edito

Puedes iterar los elementos del vector con `for of`, posterior por cada elemento con un `if else` vas a verificar con una expresión regular si el elemento termina con un valor específico

En caso de que el `if` retorne true entonces imprimimos el valor

```js
    var archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg","tarea jpg pdf","video.mp4","fondo.jpg"];
    
    for(archivo of archivos) {
      if (/[jpg]$/.test(archivo)) {
        console.log(archivo)
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Beta, sugerencia, el código fallara si cambias de lugar la extensión de los archivos.

Comment: @Riven pues edité para colocar un ejemplo colocando la extensión en el medio de la cadena de texto y aún así lo encontrará

Comment: Nope hablo en el sentido de que si esta en el medio no deberia ser filtrado, puesto que la extensión debe estar al final.

Comment: Entiendo @Riven edité y propuse otra alternativa, gracias por la observación

Answer (score 2):

Tambien puedes usar .substring

```js
var buscado = ".jpg";
var archivos = ["fotoperfil.jpg", "tarea.pdf", "video.mp4", "fondo.jpg"];
for (var i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
  if (archivos[i].substring(archivos[i].length - buscado.length, archivos[i].length) == buscado) {
    console.log(archivos[i])
  }
}
```